# Extracting elements of an ArrayList<String> as part of a Hashmap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following code:

```
for (Map.Entry < Integer, ArrayList < String >> entry: data.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    ArrayList < String > value = entry.getValue();
    for (String aString: value) {
        System.out.println("key : " + key + " value : " + aString);
    }
}
```

Hashmap is declared as

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
```

before filling it via a loop and `put` methods.

I now need to iterate the `ArrayList` of strings or better, retrieve specific elements by index .. for manipulation. I have researched as far as I can and seemed to have found the answer, with the above code. It was copied from an answer given here some time back.

However, when I try to use it complains of "Incompatible Types" with the top line underlined in red up to the colon.

- Required: `Entry <Integer,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>`
- Found:    `Entry <Integer,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>`

Comment: Change your entry to from `Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>` to `Entry<Integer, List<String>`, as well as this `ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();` to `List<String>...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have declared value type in `Hashmap`  as `List<String>` and you have given `ArrayList<String>` as value type  `Map.Entry` in `for loop`.

**change**  `Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();` to  `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: While this will solve the problem, for future readers, it is not recommended. Use abstraction when possible, in this case interface List instead of implementation ArrayList. That's one of SOLID principles.

Comment: @CrazySabbath I agree.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have the `List` interface and the `ArrayList` implementation, you have correctly used the `List` type in the declaration of the map, but you passed to declaring a implementaion (`ArrayList`) in the loop.

The problem arrises because of the statement:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
```

The empty diamond notation leaves open many options for a implementation of the `List<String>`. It can be ArrayList, LinkedList etc. So you can't be sure that the compiler will use `ArrayList` implementation.

To favour code extendibility is advisable to do what is known as *programming against interfaces*. It is always good to maintain the most generic type as long as you can to avoid coupling your code to a specific implementation, that is you will specifiy the implementation when you need to perform some concrete operation on it.

Comment: Thanks to all!! New to all this so its a bit of a curve!! ... however, it is probably my well know condition of 'domestic blindness' that prevailed here, as in my minds eye i had the HashMap defined using an ArrayList ... but not 'til it was pointed out that i had List did my vision focus on what was really on the page!! .. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
       Integer key = entry.getKey();
       List<String> value = entry.getValue();
       for(String aString : value){
            System.out.println("key : " + key + " value : " + aString);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Program against the interface rather than against an implementation.

The Map's type is `Integer` as a key and `List<String>` as a value. Thus you can loop the entries only with the very same structure.

```
for (Map.Entry < Integer, List < String >> entry: data.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    List <String> value = entry.getValue();
    for (String aString: value) {
        System.out.println("key : " + key + " value : " + aString);
    }
}
```